# wordpress-theme 2017: featured image behaviour: where to set the height of the featured image?

Tags: themes, theme-customizer

good day dear community,

after having nailed down several issues with the set up of the theme twentyseventeen - the question today is: wordpress-theme 2017: featured image behaviour: where to set the height of the featured image!?

Well while i was doing a little google-search i have found the following;
I have been searching on the whole net in order to find something useful for the solution that i can apply various (different) on the WordPress-twentyseventeen-theme:

Well what is wanted and what is needed: I have found a way to resize the so called featured image of the theme because its way too big. On post pages when you put a featured image its a perfect size on all devices, but when I try to put featured image on a regular page its way to big as well.

see the page: http://www.job-starter.com/  -  a truely beta-beta-page that only serves as a demo.

see the images that are way too big: The questions are the following ones:

– how can I adjust the size so I can make like a header for the different pages, lets say i take the following size: 800 x 175
– can i do this by pasting this little text-chunk at the end of the css – in the so called css-file:

i have this following code in the theme-customizer - "additional CSS"

question: what do i need to change - in order to make the featured image smaller!?

see the code:

```
.wrap { max-width: 1366px; }

.wrap { max-width: 1366px; }

/*For Content*/
.has-sidebar:not(.error404) #primary {
width: 60%
}

/*For Sidebar*/
.has-sidebar #secondary {
width: 30%
}

/*Responsive*/
@media(max-width:768px) {
/*For Content*/
.has-sidebar:not(.error404) #primary {
width: 100%
}

/*For Sidebar*/
.has-sidebar #secondary {
width: 100%
}
}


/* STRUCTURE */

.wrap {
max-width: 80% !important;
}

.page.page-one-column:not(.twentyseventeen-front-page) #primary {
max-width: 100% !important;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
.wrap {
max-width: 80% !important;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 30em) {

.page-one-column .panel-content .wrap {
max-width: 80% !important;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {

.wrap {
max-width: 95% !important;
}
}
```

for any and all help i thank you - all help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to theme folder of "twentyseventeen" and open the functions.php file.
Now, Goto line no. "54" and you will see below code.

```
add_image_size( 'twentyseventeen-featured-image', 2000, 1200, true );
```

You can change the dimensions there.

Thanks,

Comment: hi there - many thanks for the quick answer. tried it out - changed both values in this line - bit with allmost no effect -  i try to do further investigations.  I love to hear from you - regards

Comment: Hi there, If that didn't help you.
I would recommend you to use this plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend editing the theme itself. create a child or ... adding this to my site in the custom css section did the trick after extensive css debugging. All other "tricks" on the web did not solve anything.
I guess updates to the theme may break stuff?!

```
.has-header-image .custom-header-media img, .has-header-video .custom-header-media video, .has-header-video .custom-header-media iframe { position: absolute; }

.has-header-image.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, .has-header-video.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, .has-header-image.home.blog .custom-header, .has-header-video.home.blog .custom-header { height: 26vh; }

@media body.has-header-image .site-title, body.has-header-video .site-title, body.has-header-image .site-title a, body.has-header-video .site-title a { font-size: large; }
```